# Why browser is always showing certificate of only one server even if multiple certificates are configured in HAProxy?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I am a beginner in HAProxy. I have four VMs, with HAProxy in one and Apache httpd in other three. What I am trying to achieve is, when user connect to HAProxy IP using https, the connection should be redirected to any of the other three servers. Please find my configuration below;

```
global
    maxconn 50000
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    user root
    group root
    stats timeout 30s
    nbproc 2
    cpu-map auto:1/1-4 0-3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 no-tls-tickets
    daemon

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend ft_http
    bind :80
    mode http
    default_backend bk_http

frontend ft_https
    bind :443 ssl crt-list /etc/haproxy/crt-list.txt
    mode tcp
    default_backend bk_https

backend bk_http
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    default-server inter 1s
    server testserver1 192.168.0.1:80 check
    server testserver2 192.168.0.2:80 check
    server testserver3 192.168.0.3:80 check

backend bk_https
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 1m
    default-server inter 1s
    server testserver1 192.168.0.1:443 check
    server testserver2 192.168.0.2:443 check
    server testserver3 192.168.0.3:443 check
```

and below is how `crt-list.txt` looks like;

```
/etc/haproxy/testserver1.pem testserver1
/etc/haproxy/testserver2.pem testserver2
/etc/haproxy/testserver3.pem testserver3
```

I have generated certificates by referring these urls https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-https-on-apache-centos/ and https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018152

Now, whenever I hit https://haproxy_ip in my browser, the browser prompt unsigned certificate and it always belongs to `testserver1`. Certificate of other two servers are not getting picked  up.

And, When I accept the certificate and proceed, I am getting a page with content like below;

```
# Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

Apache/2.2.34 (Amazon) Server at testserver1.localdomain Port 443
```

and whenever I reload the page, the last line of message changes like `Apache/2.2.34 (Amazon) Server at testserver2.localdomain Port 443` and `Apache/2.2.34 (Amazon) Server at testserver2.localdomain Port 443` (but when I take the certificate, it is the one I created for `testserver1`)

Now, my question is, why am I always getting the certificate of `testserver1`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no load balancing in the certificates HAproxy offers.

The front-end always presents the best certificate for the hostname used in the SNI handshake. The best certificate is the one where the `CN` or a `SAN` entry in one of the certificates matches the URI used in the request and if no such match can be made, the default certificate is used.

The option [`crt-list`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#5.1-crt-list) uses the first entry as the default certificate.

Also the certificate presented at the front-end bears no relation to which back-end server HAProxy connects.
Unless your load balancer operates at the TCP/IP level and only forwards the connection, the load balancer is the man in the middle; the client connects to the load balancer and the load balancer makes its own new connection to the backend to forward the request

From the manual:

> The first declared certificate of a bind line is used as the default certificate, either from `crt` or `crt-list` option, which haproxy should use in
> the TLS handshake if no other certificate matches. This certificate will also
> be used if the provided SNI matches its CN or SAN, even if a matching SNI
> filter is found on any crt-list. The SNI filter !* can be used after the first
> declared certificate to not include its CN and SAN in the SNI tree, so it will
> never match except if no other certificate matches. This way the first
> declared certificate act as a fallback

Comment: I understand your point. Could you please tell me is it possible to bind multiple certificate to my haproxy, and deliver appropriate certificate according to url pattern?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what your configuration currently does